# delete only one {key:value } pair from one row in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

collection name- team1
under team1 I have this row of data as following-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59a36a757a3d6759f63a7f18"), "name" : "chinux", "age" : 10, "color" : "white" }
```

From the above row I want to delete only `{name:"chiunx"}`.

If I try to delete this with command - `db.team1.remove({name : "chinux"})`it deletes the complete row. How can I delete only one property mentioned above?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $unset

```
db.team1.update({ _id: ObjectId("59a36a757a3d6759f63a7f18")}, {$unset: {name: ""});
```

Answer (score 1):

`db.team1.update({"_id" : ObjectId("59a36a757a3d6759f63a7f18")}, {$unset: {name:1}});`

Please refer the following link.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/